# How to put a Svelte app in a docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker, svelte

The title pretty much says it all. I am very new to web development.

I created a Svelte app using `npx degit sveltejs/template ...`. Now I run it locally using `npm run dev` or `npm start`.

To my understanding, this is a Node server, but adapting their [official tutorial](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/) didn't get me very far.

I found a [blog post](http://sciencevikinglabs.com/svelte-in-docker/) about this, but it doesn't quite explain how to dockerize an existing Svelte app, instead points to a [fork](https://github.com/ScienceVikings/svelte-template) of the official template.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can place a `Dockerfile` in your app directory (where `package.json` is):

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY rollup.config.js ./
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./public ./public

RUN npm run-script build

EXPOSE 5000

ENV HOST=0.0.0.0

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Build a local image:

```
$ docker build -t svelte/myapp .
```

And run it:

```
$ docker run -p 5000:5000 svelte/myapp
```

Comment: Apologies for only now getting around to try your suggested solution. Thanks!

Comment: Can you modify your answer adding the steps to execute a build every time? Otherwise one would have to build manually before each Docker build. This is the code I ended up using.
```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY rollup.config.js ./
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./public ./public

RUN npm run-script build

EXPOSE 5000

ENV HOST=0.0.0.0

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: @ticofab i am failing to get any page back all I get Is 404 error from the docker image i have deployed on my was what could be the cause of it ?

Comment: @ticofab, I have managed to get the app to work from my the docker image on was but I see that it's failing to create the build folder in the public folder I have tried to change the commands in the docker file but its an issue still

Comment: Has anyone managed to make this work with Watch enabled on Rollup? I've mounted the /src directory in as a Volume and verified that the files inside the container are updated, but the `npm run dev` Rollup process which has watch enabled, is not reacting to the changes to the file.

Comment: @GarethOates Are you using Windows as host by any chance?

Comment: Yes I am.  I'm guessing that's the problem?

Comment: My understanding is that Windows Hosts +  Docker have problems with reloading/watching tasks like Rollup and Webpack. Could be completely FUD... Maybe make sure -you have the latest Docker version installed...

Comment: @GarethOates my current workaround (on windows with docker toolbox) is to run rollup on the host and sirv in the docker container in parallel and mirroring the src/ and public dirs as docker volumes. (Alternatively, mirroring public/ to a basic webserver container should  be a simpler workaround.)

Comment: There is documentation for that: https://svelte-recipes.netlify.app/publishing

Comment: I have seen cases where they deploy the svelte app behind nginx. I am not sure what is better production wise.

Answer (score 1):

Now **SvelteJs** and **SvelteKit** Uses **ViteJs** . For building a minimized **SvelteJs/SvelteKit** docker image you can use this dockerfile commands

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:19 as build

ENV NODE_ENV=production 


WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build


FROM node:19-alpine3.16

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .


ENV HOST=0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 4173
CMD ["npm","run", "preview","--", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Here , Vitejs preview serves in `PORT 4173` that's why i used `EXPOSE 4173` and `--host 0.0.0.0` will expose the port outside the container . From my experience **nodejs alpine** image gives small and reliable Docker images.

Comment: Doesn't work. Show err: 
```failed to load config from /app/vite.config.ts

error during build:```

I'm using pnpm

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the answers are quite outdated and not what i needed, Let me help abit.

The main problem i faced was in deploying a svelte/sveltekit app with docker using a dockerfile for `production` and `optimized for production` as well.

Using the Dockerfile provided above one would have to update it to look like this:

- for my instance i will make use of `pnpm` though, other package managers like `yarn` and `npm` can be used as well.

```docker
# bookworm images are more secure compared to alpine
FROM node:20.10-bookworm-slim as build

ENV NODE_ENV=production 

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./
COPY pnpm-lock.yaml ./

# pnpm must be installed as it doesn't come with the default image
RUN npm i -g pnpm
RUN pnpm i
COPY . ./

RUN pnpm build

FROM node:20.10-bookworm-slim

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
# ENV HOST is not though you can uncomment if if needed
# ENV HOST=0.0.0.0
 EXPOSE 4173

CMD ["node","build"]
```

**package.json{scripts}** 
this is the script section for the package.json

```json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "vite dev",
  "build": "vite build",
  "preview": "vite preview",
  "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
  "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch",
  "test:unit": "vitest run",
  "test:ui": "vitest --ui",
  "test:integration": "playwright test",
  "coverage": "vitest run --coverage",
  "lint": "prettier --check . && eslint .",
  "format": "prettier  --write ."
},
```

**Note**: I would advice to only use `npm run preview` / `pnpm preview` only in local environment to ensure that the production version used will look the same,
in Production after `pnpm build` only make use of `node build` which is optimized for production.